# How to render and map an object using a variable as a key in react

Tags: reactjs, dictionary, filter, state

I've been tasked with creating a clone of the popular game show Family Feud. I am having trouble finding a good way to take a list of "rounds" each with a question and an array of answers (something like)

```
const Data = {
  round_1: {
    question: "A question",
    answers: ["one answer", "second one", ...etc]
  },
  round_2: {
    question: ...,
    answers: [...]
  },
  ...etc
}
```

and then rendering the relevant round info into a component such that the player can go forward and back rounds and only have the relevant rounds info mapped to the component. Something like:

```
// Gameboard.js
import React from 'react'
import {Data} from './data'
export default class extends React.Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    const round = 1
    const ansArray = []
    const roundQuestion = Data.round_`${round}`.question
    const roundAnswers = Data.round_`${round}`.answers.map(ans=>{
      ansArray.push(ans)
    })
    this.setState({
      question: roundQuestion,
      answers: roundAnswers
    })
  }
handlePrevRoundClick() {
  this.setState({set to prev round})
}
handleNextRoundClick() {
  this.setState....
}
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <RoundInfo roundNum={this.state.round}/>
      <Round answers={this.state.answers}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Then obviously the components RoundInfo and Round are merely passed their info via props. I have left them off the example because I think that the logic i'm after only applies to this main "Gameboard" component. I would be more than happy to expand if necessary. I also realize that there may be typos and missing bits here. I'd be happy to jsfiddle it if anyone needs a bit more to go on. I do have a working prototype which i have manually created each rounds' own component but this is decidedly not the React Way...

In summary: I am asking for methods to use a variable to "walk" back and forth between a list of objects, only having to map the current rounds' info to the board.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's like you already did most of the job. To complete what you did:

```
// Gameboard.js
export default class extends React.Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    // init round to 0
    this.setState({
      round:0
    });
  }
  handlePrevRoundClick = () => {
    const round = this.state.round - 1;
    this.setState({round}); // update round
  }
  handleNextRoundClick= () => {
    const round = this.state.round + 1;
    this.setState({round}); // update round
  }
  render() {
    const curRoundData = Data['round_'+this.state.round];
    return (
      <div>
        <RoundInfo roundNum={this.state.round}/>
        <Round answers={curRoundData.answers}/>
        <div onClick={this.handlePrevRoundClick}>Go Prev</div>
        <div onClick={this.handleNextRoundClick}>Go Next</div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: What I mean is: the data for each round has a key "round_X" I need to set state to the current selected Round as well as the question and answers... make sense?

Comment: Your example is only changing the round number and not any of the data...

Comment: Yay! Yes. I will give her a try and accept your answer here in a moment! Thanks